# Using user CSS sheet in a template

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm using Django to display user uploaded static HTML and CSS files. The HTML isn't a problem, however I can't get Django to actually render using the uploaded CSS.

Project structure is the following:

```
my_project
    main_app
    display_app
    my_project
    media
        user
            whatever.html
            whatver.css
```

My main url.py contains:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^html_uploads/', include('display_app.urls')),
url(r'^', include('main_app.urls')),] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

display_app urls.py is:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^(?P<requested>(?:[\w]+\/?)+)$', views.readhtml, name='requested'),]
```

The relevant part of the view is:

```
def read_html(request, file_name):
    title = 'html_file_title'
    body = get_body(file_name)
    css_source = 'user/whatever.css'
    return render(request, "display_app/base.html",
            {'title': title,
            'body': body,
            'css_source': css_source,
            'media_url': settings.MEDIA_URL,}
            )
```

The CSS simply contains:

```
body {
background-color: #FFCC66
}
```

And the template looks like:

```
<head>
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ media_url }}{{ css_source }}" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
{% autoescape off %}
    {{ body }}
{% endautoescape %}
</body>
```

With this, I get a 404 as Django fails to find /media/user/whatever.css.

If I change the CSS location to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/{{ media_url }}{{ css_source }}" type="text/css" />
```

The 404 warning disappears, the HTML still loads, however the CSS is silently ignored.

The HTML is passed through several functions and heavily modified, therefore passing it as a string made sense, however the CSS should be used directly and I was hoping to load it from the template instead.
What's going on there? Does not getting a 404 warning mean Django is locating the CSS file correctly? If it is, why is it not used?

Comment: Things to try: follow the CSS link in the rendered template; render the CSS directly as a string in the template, similar to the body.

Comment: try to use <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css_source' %}" type="text/css" /> after this use collectstatic command.